# Angularjs select option ng-selected select blank option for assign value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller:

```
$scope.usercountry[key]='101'; //this one is selected correctly
$scope.usercountry[key]=value.countryid;  //this is not selected
```

selected in html view are

HTML:

```
 <select id ="red" style="width:90%;" class="form-control state state1" name="state_list" ng-change="getstate(0)" ng-model="usercountry[0]">
    <option value="">--Country--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="country in countryies" ng-selected="country.id==selectedCountryvalue[0]" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.country}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is vary fogy can you be more specific?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What does not work? What should be the result? Please be more specific, as it stands, no one will be able to help you. Please also add the JSON or code for `countries`

Answer (score 0):

ng-options helps you bind objects to select values.

Try something like this:

html

```
{{usercountry}}
<select ng-options="country as country.country for country in countries" ng-model="usercountry"></select>
```

angularJS

```
$scope.countries = [
    {id: 0, country: "Italy"}, {id: 1, country: "Greece"}
];

$scope.usercountry = $scope.countries[0];
```

If you have any more questions, let me know :)